# Sometimes my Android Apps don't start

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

Sometimes my users have problems to start my apps. It seems that the app starts but the screens stays black. There is no crash report, because the app don't really crashes. So i have no idea what I can do to avoid this problem. Perhaps someone had similar problems and could give me a hint, what i cant do.

My app is a simple notpad app. The Text of one TextView is saved in a String which is saved in the preferences onDestroy, onPause and onStop in the same way.
This is my onDestroy method:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
       super.onDestroy();
       text = Text.getText().toString();
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
       editor.putString("Text", text);
       editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you had some sample code of the app so we can see the potential cause of the crashing; Sometimes, you might have  memory issues that gets your app killed or some other issue

Comment: Try to figure out if it happens on a "fresh" start or only on "restarts", i.e. if the `onDestroy` method of your `Activity` gets called. Then, step by step try to strip execution which might cause hanging of your app. If the problem's gone, that's where you need to look.

Comment: ok mom i will add some code...

Comment: I would log up my code and make sure everything is doing what you expect it to.

Comment: i had no problems with my app when i tested it. Even when i have a very big string the app starts very fast on my system. i only see that some people seem to have these problems when they rate my app...

Comment: could there a problem, that i do initiate settings and editor three times on onDestroy, onPause and onStop?

Comment: typically you save state in onPause() and clean up resources in onDestroy()